# Кожевник, шорник, скорняк

Tags: этимология

Почему тот, кто работает с кожей, называется не только кожевник, шорник (эти слова понятны), но и скорняк?

Answer (score 3):

Скорняк образовано от скорьнь "сапог", которое в свою очередь от скорА "шкура" (Словарь Фасмера)

Comment: А есть еще кожевенник (1. работник кожевенной промышленности; 2. то же что кожевник)